# Adding a class to collection_radio_buttons in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I simply have a form and at the top of my form are some radio buttons. Everything has the "form-control" class and flows perfectly fine horizontally; however, I can't get this same class applied to this:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :realm, [['External','External'], ['Internal','Internal']], :first, :last %>
```

I've been looking around, but can only find others who are doing something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the form-control class on both the button and label?  Then you are looking for something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :realm, [['External','External'], ['Internal','Internal']], :first, :last do |b| %>
  <%- b.label(class: "form-control") { b.radio_button(class: "form-control") } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually realized that something else was the problem and I may have explained this wrongly. I appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 0):

The [syntax](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons) is

```
collection_radio_buttons(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

You don't have any options, so you need to supply an empty hash before the `html_options` hash.

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :parent_id, [['External','External'], ['Internal','Internal']], :first, :last, {}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
```